# How to write a file transactionnaly?

Tags: java, file

I want to know if there is a wayin JAVA  to ensure  that  writting of bytes in a new file is transactionnaly.

If an exception occured during the writing, the file must not be created

Thanks

Comment: A common way of doing that is writing to a temp file, and once you know that the writing is successful, move the temp file to the real location. Both files must be on the same partition for that to work, though.

Comment: In what environment? Java EE? Spring Service? Desktop?

Comment: `...the file must not be created` - so it is only for new files? In that case you could just create the file and delete it afterward and as njzk2 said, you could use a (hidden) temp file and copy/move it on success in order to prevent it being visible or even read until the transaction is successful.

Comment: @njzk2 You should turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you can do something like that:

```
public static boolean write(byte[] content, String filepath) {
    File tmp = new File(filepath + ".tmp");
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
        out.write(content);
        out.close();
        // At this point the file is correctly written
        tmp.renameTo(new File(filepath));
        // Now the file is renamed to the final place
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tmp.delete();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Create a temp file, write to it, if all goes according to plan, rename the file.

Note that it is very important that the tmp file is in the same partition as the final file, as the move is literally a rename, while if not, it is a copy-and-delete.

Comment: Thanks for your responses,

Comment: But how can i manage the case of  destination is via network if a connection is failed during  the copying of file Env : Java EE

Comment: that's up to whoever receives the file to to handle that, not to the client that sends the file.